# How to handle continuously stream messages?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency

I am developing an Android application where there is a background thread that is connected with a server through a sort of stream connection. My background thread has to handle every message received ( about 5-6 messages in a second) and in some cases update the UI thread using data received from messages.
My question is: what is **the best approach** to handle messages?

I am wondering about three solutions:

- handle the message in the loop;
- handle every message in a new thread;
- handle every message using ExecutorService and a Callable Task with a Timeout.

I am looking for the most efficent solution, if there could be more solutions than only these 3 please tell me what they could be, I am very interested in knowing new approaches for concurrent development 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a chat application? 5-6 messages every second for how long?

Comment: No, it is not a chat application. I have some devices that are streaming their data through a server that is streaming this data to all the Android devices running this app, and I need to parse these messages, store them and sometimes show on the UI.

Comment: @NitinSethi: for how long... till the user exits the application. The app is based on communication between devices - server - Android application devices.

Comment: it dependents dude, is the sequence of message are important or the very last one would cover the previous ones?!

Comment: The sequence is important, only few of these messages ( streaming general data ) could be lost.